# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined p5.js/node.js/socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, p5.js

I'm having an error when the second client is connected. My code comparing the two clients current position by **p5.Vector.dist()** and there's an error, here it is.

[image]

And the line in **p5.Vector.dist(p5.js:25914)** is

```js
p5.Vector.prototype.dist = function (v) {
  var d = v.copy().sub(this); //This is the exact line where the error says from
  return d.mag();
};
```

This is my code;

Client side;

```js
//I use for loop to see all the contain of otherCircles
for(var x = 0; x < otherCircles.length; x++){
  if(otherCircles[x].id != socket.id){ //To make sure i won't compare the client's data to its own because the data of all connected client's is here
   console.log(otherCircles[x].radius); //To see if the data is not null
   if(circle.eat(otherCircles[x])){
    if(circle.radius * 0.95 >= otherCircles[x].radius){
     otherCircles.splice(x,1);
     console.log('ATE');
    } else if(circle.radius <= otherCircles[x].radius * 0.95){
     zxc = circle.radius;
     asd = zxc;
     circle.radius = null;
     console.log('EATEN');
    }
   }
  }
 }

//Here's the eat function of the circle

function Circle(positionX,positionY,radius){
//The variables of Circle()
        this.position = createVector(positionX, positionY);
 this.radius = radius;
 this.velocity = createVector(0, 0);
  
  //Here's the eat function
  this.eat = function(other) {
      var distance = p5.Vector.dist(this.position, other.position); //Heres where the error 
      if (distance < this.radius + (other.radius * 0.25)) { //Compare there distance
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

The **otherCircles[]** contains;

[image]

And that is also the output of the line **console.log(otherCircles[x].radius);**.

I don't think the server side would be necessary because it only do is to receive the current position and size of the client and send the other clients position and size to. All there datas stored in **otherCircles()**. The line **console.log(otherCircles[x].radius);** result is not null, so I know there's data where being compared to the clients position, why I'm having an error like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be pretty hard to help you without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I'll try to walk you through debugging this.

You've printed `otherCircles[x].radius`, which is a good start. But if I were you, I'd want to know much more about `otherCircles[x]`. What variables and functions does it contain? I'd start by googling "JavaScript print function names of object" and try to figure out exactly what's in that object. What is the value of `otherCircles[x].position`?

From there, I'd also want to make sure that `otherCircles[x].position` is defined and an instance of `p5.Vector`. Does it have a `copy()` function?

I might also step through the code with a debugger- every browser has one, and you should become familiar with using it.

If you still can't get it work, then please post an MCVE that we can run by copy-pasting it. That means no server code, just hard-code your values so we can see the same error. I'd bet you find your problem while trying to narrow it down to a small example. But if not, we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I edited the post, I post what are the contains of the object **otherCircles[]**.

Comment: However, your answer helps me to found out the error, the **p5.Vector.dist()** is only accepting a Vector and not a x and y position, I should use **createVector()** to use the **p5.Vector.dist()** Thank you Mr. Workman.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate That's pretty much exactly what my answer was trying to help you discover. Glad you got it figured out.